# Should I map Modality values to SOP Class UIDs?

Tags: dicom

Is it reliable to map modalities to `SOPClassUID`s? In other words, does a one-one mapping for `SOPClassUID` to modality is fine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a one-to-one mapping is not possible.  Consider this common example where 4 SOP Class UIDs all map to 'US':

```
1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.6    Ultrasound Image Storage (Retired)
1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.6.1  Ultrasound Image Storage
1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3    Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage (Retired)
1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1  Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage
```

If you had an object for each one of the SOP Class UIDs shown above, they would all have 'US' in the modality tag.

So if you just look at 'US' in modality tag 0008,0060, is it a single-frame or multi-frame echo image?  It is better to consider the SOP Class UID for precisely defining the type of DICOM object you are dealing with.

Reference:  see "Annex A Registry of DICOM unique identifiers (UID)" of [Part 6 of the standard](http://medical.nema.org/dicom/2003/03_06PU.PDF).

Comment: Add to this ,the secondary Capture SOPs may contain different modalities

Comment: Yes, you are right. One-to-_one_ mapping is not possible, But it sounds to me that OP wants to deduce modality from the value of SOPClassUID tag. _This_ is possible, but not the other way round.

Comment: @chris Thanks Chris! one-one mapping is not possible fine. I need to confirm one more thing. Could I say this this is many-one? also I want to make sure one-many is not possible. i.e., given a SOPClassUID. I could say the modality without ambiguity. rit?

Comment: @Kannan Unfortunately not, given a single object you can _usually_ determine the object's modality from the SOP Class or Modality tag.  But as pointed out (thanks @SaraS) the secondary capture SOPs have a Modality of 'SC', they are post-processed images generated from other images in the same study.  Also, the Comprehensive SR is commonly sent by ultrasound machines for ongoing measurements, but depending on what you are doing, you might care about its literal modality of 'SR' for that object, you might care more about the fact that the entire study is 'US' (coming from ultrasound machine).

Comment: "SC" is not one of the defined term for the Modality (0008,0060) attribute. So, Secondary Capture SOPs cannot use it. "OT" meaning "Other" is the best default for Secondary Capture SOPs.

Answer (score 0):

From what you can see [here](http://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/sop/), this is indeed possible. Actually, storing correct modality information in the [modality (0008,0060) tag](http://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/modality/) is obligatory. I have never used SOPClassUID for that, because this would be so cumbersome, but yes, this is possible.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not correct, a one-to-one mapping is not possible.

Comment: I completely agree with Chris O. One-to-one mapping just based on Modality Tag (0008:0060) is not possible. I have seen different values for Modality tag such as "CT", "MR", and “US" etc for Secondary Capture SOPs.

Answer (score 0):

**One to one mapping**:

No; not possible. Reason and example is already given in accepted answer. US modality value may be included in multiple SOP Classes. Private SOP Classes for specific modalities is another example.

**One to many mapping**:

One modality value cannot be mapped with multiple SOP classes in reliable way. Secondary Capture SOP class is an example here. Any modality value could be assigned to this class; generally SC or OT is used.

**Equipment sending different values for same study**:

Further to above, an equipment (modality) may send instances with multiple modality values. Pet CT equipment may send instances with PT and CT value in Modality tag. Almost any equipment may include instances with SC/OT value. Modality value SR is also used by many equipment to transfer report data.

---

SOP Class value and Modality value have their own purposes and the values should be used in same way. One should not try to overlap the purpose. I agree there is **some** relation between those two; but do not just rely on it. Use each tag for it's intended purpose.